# Обновление версии Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

Здравствуйте. После обновления Node.js с версии 4.6.2 до 9.3.0 выскакивает ошибка при попытке запустить server.js. Пол гугла перерыл, что-то все не то. Вот ошибка

```js
## There is an issue with `node-fibers` ##
`/var/www/cubecover_dev/node_modules/fibers/bin/linux-x64-59/fibers.node` is missing.

Try running this to fix the issue: /usr/local/bin/node /var/www/cubecover_dev/node_modules/fibers/build
/var/www/cubecover_dev/node_modules/fibers/fibers.js:20
 throw new Error('Missing binary. See message above.');
 ^

Error: Missing binary. See message above.
    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/www/cubecover_dev/node_modules/fibers/fibers.js:20:8)
    at Module._compile (module.js:660:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:671:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:573:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:513:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:505:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:604:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/www/cubecover_dev/node_modules/asyncawait/src/fibers.js:1:75)
    at Module._compile (module.js:660:30)
```

Как можно решить и предупредить дальнейшее появление?

Comment: Пробовали переустанавливать node_modules?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Тут же сказано: **Try running this to fix the issue:** (попробуйте запустить это, чтобы исправить проблему) `/usr/local/bin/node /var/www/cubecover_dev/node_modules/fibers/build` (желательно от суперпользователя).

Comment: Для понимая: проблема именно так и была решена, с помощью команды node в терминале вызвал поочередно сначала build, потом fiber.js